# Can I infer time zone from offset AND a datetime?

Tags: timezone, offset

I know that I can't get a time zone purely from its offset, as mentioned in the wiki page for the time zone tag here.

What if I also had the datetime though? That would narrow things down to where I don't have to worry about daylight savings time.

I'm not looking for a locale. Just the time zone. I think this question is relevant because everything I've found online indicates clearly that you cannot get time zone from offset, but nothing clearly states that you can't get time zone from offset+datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if I also had the datetime though?

No, it still doesn't give you enough information.

It's entirely possible for two time zones to have the same local time at the same instant *right now*, but to diverge a minute later. Just knowing the date/time and offset does *not* give you a time zone - at least not in general. In many cases it *might* - for any given situation, you *could* look through all the time zones and check how many of them have that UTC offset at that instant in time... but you should definitely expect there to be cases where the answer is "more than one time zone matches".

As a concrete example, consider 2022-05-16T17:33:00+01:00. That matches Africa/Casablanca and Europe/London *at least* - but those are definitely very different time zones with different rules.

Comment: 2022-05-16T17:33:00+01:00 also matches Africa/Douala, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Tunis, Africa/Bangui, Africa/Libreville, Europe/Jersey, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Malabo, Africa/Algiers, Africa/Ndjamena, Africa/Kinshasa, Africa/Lagos, Atlantic/Canary, Atlantic/Madeira, Europe/Belfast, Africa/Niamey, Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Lisbon, Atlantic/Faeroe, Africa/Luanda, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Europe/Dublin and Africa/Porto-Novo.

Answer (score 0):

## The long answer (TLDR at the bottom)

Having a timezone in a timestamp is just an indicator to help understand when the event specifically happened in time. The time you get in the timestamp is the time that it was at that moment, on that location, with the  ***at the time*** timeOffset.

Nothing guarantees that that time offset is going to be always the same. Countries use Daylight saving times or might decide to cancel them for any specific reason.

In the browser world, there are tools in the Date and Intl class that can help you reconstruct/extract that information.

The best way to get the timezone is to ask the user for it. Otherwise, there are ways like checking the browser's timezone (not available for Firefox) or using the geolocation API.

#### Using the Browser's timezone (Except for Firefox as Jan 24)

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

#### Using the geolocation at the browser, and then using a library to get the timeZone:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(console.log)
```

#### Recreating a date with the known timeZone:

Again, assuming we are talking in the browser world, if you want to show a timestamp with a timezone different to the one in the user's browser location, you can do that by using the Intl class. The problem is, that to use it you must know the timeZone.

```
console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    dateStyle: 'full',
    timeStyle: 'long',
    timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney',
  }).format(date),
);
```

### TLDR; The short answer

No, it wouldn't be enough. You would need to know it by asking the user, getting it from the browser, or getting the geolocation coordinates, and map it to the correct timeZone.

In any case, knowing the timeZone would only be helpful if you need to show the timestamp with the original location when the user is on another location.